# Unable to execute Ruby script in a Python script

Tags: python, ruby, cron

I'm having trouble executing a Ruby script with my Python code.

My server has a cron job that is supposed to execute a Python script and a Ruby script. However, the Ruby script has to be executed after the Python one, so I decided to add a line:

```
os.system("ruby /home/username/helloworld.rb")
```

at the end of the Python script.

It runs, but I'm getting this error in the log file:

```
/bin/sh 1: ruby not found
```

I'm not sure why this is happening; I've tried calling the exact same function in the Python console as well as running the Python script manually, and both work perfectly. In other words, this line of code doesn't work *ONLY* when the script is triggered by cron.

Is there something else I need to put in my crontab/Python script perhaps?

Comment: My guess would be that cron runs with a different PATH setting than yourself. I would start by trying to specify the complete path to ruby instead of just calling it like this.

Comment: @rje thanks that's exactly what I needed to do! Didn't remember I'd been using `rbenv` until you mentioned the PATH setting. If you'd like please answer the question and I shall mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron passes only a very limited number of environment variables to your job. According to the [CRONTAB(5) Man Page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab%285%29):

- `SHELL` is set to `/bin/sh`
- `PATH` is set to `/usr/bin:/bin`
- `LOGNAME` and `HOME` are set from the `/etc/passwd` line of the crontab's
   owner.

> `HOME`, `PATH`    and `SHELL` may be overridden by settings in the
>   crontab; `LOGNAME` may not.

So if your `ruby` executable is not located in either `/usr/bin` or `/bin` cron cannot find it by default.

You can a specify `PATH` within crontab to include your ruby executable though.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

17 * * * * python my_ruby_calling_script.py
```

Comment: Are the colons used to separate all the potential `PATH`s? Does that mean `cron` will then search all 4 locations before returning a `not found` error?

Comment: `PATH` contains a colon-separated list of directories in which your system looks for executable files. So, yes!